# Calling [[super allocWithZone:nil] init], messaging mechanism

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, nsobject

f. e. (just for understanding messages mechanism more clear) I have class

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
   int ivar1;
   int ivar2;
}

+ (id)instance;

@end
```

MyClass.m

```
static MyClass* volatile _sInstance = nil;

@implementation MyClass

+ (id)instance {
       if (!_sInstance) {
       @synchronized(self) {
           if (!_sInstance) {
               _sInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
           }
       }
   }
   return _sInstance;
}

@end
```

What will be send in objc_msgSend in fact when calling `[super allocWithZone:nil]` ?

`objc_msgSend([MyClass class], "allocWithZone", nil)` or `objc_msgSend([NSObject class], "allocWithZone", nil)` ?

In practice I think that called `objc_msgSend(self, "allocWithZone", nil)` and in that case `self == [MyClass class];`

I want to be sure that memory for ivar1 and ivar2 will be allocated.

Is it true, that when we call super in class method, in objc_msgSend() function the "self" argument is passed, that in our case  is class object of child? And allocWithZone will "look" at the child class object to see how much memory should be allocated for ivar1 and ivar2.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something by why would you allocate an instance of `MyClass` by calling `[[MyClass super] alloc]`?

Comment: @trojanfoe It can be "alloc" method, it is not so important )

Comment: But what I don't understand is how calling `[super alloc]` (or `[super allocWithZone]`) will allocate enough space for the additional instance variables in `self`?

Comment: So that was my question) I think that will be passed "self" that will be [MyClass class], and from [MyClass class] it will se how much space will be enough

Comment: @trojanfoe It does not matter whether or not to call `alloc` using `super` or `self`. The runtime uses the receiver to determine the instance size.

Comment: As my answer explains, a super call sends both the super class and the receiver to the runtime. Only the receiver is passed to the method implementation then.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe OK thanks - interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any message to `super` is translated by the compiler to `objc_msgSendSuper` (not `objc_msgSend`). The first argument is a pointer to a struct. The struct contains a pointer to the super class of the current implementation and the a pointer to the receiver. The former is needed during runtime to search for the overridden implementation, the latter is used as the first argument.

In the case of a class method the receiver is again a class pointer, yet not the same as the `super_class`. In your case the receiver is a `MyClass` pointer while the `super_class` pointer would be `NSObject`.

Two side notes: I recommend against putting energy in writing the fanciest Singleton. Better leave it up to the developer to create his own instances or use the provided shared instance. And please note that [double-checked locking is broken](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).